# Problem with declaring a dynamic array of pointers to strings

Tags: c++, string

While performing a practice assignment online I came across a problem which I am not able to solve.

The user has to a number(number of sentences he will be entering) and then proceed to enter the sentences one by one, which are to be stored as strings(by the way, declaring a dynamic array of pointers is mandatory). However, since the number of sentences is not a priori deducible, I know that the size of the array of pointers actually is the number of sentences but I can't figure out how to *declare a dynamic array of pointers to strings*.

Using something I had already known beforehand, I figured out how to do the same but with arrays of characters, not arrays of strings. The line that declared a dynamic array of pointers to dynamic arrays of chars looked like this:

```
char **ptr=new char*[n] {};
```

So with my understanding, this creates a pointer `ptr` which points to a dynamic array of pointers, the elements of which each point to one array of characters. I want to do something similar now, where the result should be that `ptr` is a pointer to a dynamic array of pointers, the elements of which each point to a string.

Can anyone help out? I'd be thankful!

Comment: Are you willing to use a `std::string`, or do you want to do this in C with `char` pointers?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I have to use `std::string` for this one.

Comment: And by the way, I'm talking about C++, not C

Comment: So, you want something like `std::string *ptr` and new that

Comment: @doctorlove exactly! That is what I want!

Comment: Just to clarify: you must use many `std::string` and store them using a pointer?

Comment: Do you have to use `char **ptr=new char*[n] {};`? If so do you also have to use `std::string` (you say so, but are you sure?) There is a disconnect in using basic pointer types to information contained in `std::string` -- it's doable, just wonky. You would essentially be reading with 1 `std::string` then using the `.length()` and `.c_str()` members to size a block to copy to and then assign the address of that block to one of your pointers are read the next string. A vector of strings makes more sense, but often that isn't allowed in these exercises.

Comment: It would be much more consistent to use the standard C-string with `char **ptr=new char*[n] {};`, but, it's your question...

Comment: @Walter Yes!

@DavidC.Rankin Let me try to explain it more clearly(Sorry if I did not do it the first time). Say you enter a number(2) and enter two sentences "It is" and "raining". Both sentences have to be `std::string`. My code would have to dynamically allocate an array of two pointers, the first one pointing to "It is" and the second one to "raining".

Yes, I know that I would not have problems if I use `std::vector<std::string>>` but this is purposefully left as an exercise so I could better understand the mechanics of pointers.

Comment: Gotcha and @doctorlove has got a pretty good approach to that one. If you need more strings, you will have to write a realloc scheme where you basically declare a newset of pointers (with double the number), copy old to new, `delete[] old` and then set `old=newset` and keep going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like

```
std::size_t num;
std::cout << "enter the number of sentences\n";
std::cin  >> num;
std::string *sentences = new std::string[num];
for(std::size_t i=0; i!=num; ++i) {
    std::cout << "enter the " << (i+1) << "th sentence\n";
    std::cin  >> sentences[i];
}
/* 
    ... (do something with the sentences, accessing them as sentences[i])
*/
delete[] sentences;     // free the memory
```

Note that this style of coding is **highly discouraged**. The problem is the need to manage the allocated memory: avoid memory leaks and dangling pointers (including exception safety). The correct approach is to use a container or smart pointer. For example:

```
std::size_t num;
std::cout << "enter the number of sentences\n";
std::cin  >> num;
std::vector<std::string> sentences{num};
for(std::size_t i=0; i!=num; ++i) {
    std::cout << "enter the " << (i+1) << "th sentence\n";
    std::cin  >> sentences[i];
}
/* 
    ... (do something with the sentences, accessing them as sentences[i])
*/
```

or

```
std::size_t num;
std::cout << "enter the number of sentences\n";
std::cin  >> num;
std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> sentences{new std::string[num]};
for(std::size_t i=0; i!=num; ++i) {
    std::cout << "enter the " << (i+1) << "th sentence\n";
    std::cin  >> sentences[i];
}
/* 
    ... (do something with the sentences, accessing them as sentences[i])
*/
```

when in both cases you don't have to worry about calling `delete`: the allocated memory will be automatically deleted (even if an exception occurs).

Comment: Thank you very much, that seemed to work. I have one more question though(if you have the time to reply).

I think I may have come up with this on my own, but what confuses me is `std::string *sentences = new std::string[num];`. 

`sentences` is a pointer to strings, but `new std::string[num]` is something I haven't seen before. Isn't `std::string` internally a dynamically allocated array? What would `new` do in conjunction with string? 

Once again I am sorry for my ignorance, I am really new to this. Thank you for your immense help!

Comment: @I0ner9 If this answer was helpful, please upvote it and/or accept it. As to your additional question. This is standard `operator new[]` syntax, as in `int *ptr = new int[42];`, only that instead of `int` you allocate `std::string`. Yes, internally `std::string` *may* also use dynamic allocation to store long strings, but that does not matter here: the `new` operator only allocates the memory actually needed by the `std::string`, not the additional memory that the strings then may allocate.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid pointers completely and use

```
std::vector<std::string> input;
```

A `std::array` needs to know the size at compile time, and you learn this at runtime. The vector works like an array but can have items `push_back`ed at runtime.

You could declare pointer to some strings, using `n` once you know it:

```
std::string * pInputs = new std::string[n];
```

but it's easier to use the vector.
Each `pInput` will be a string, as with the `std::vector` version.